# Standalone transparent activity is showing in recents holding previous intent

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin

I have a StandaloneActivity which handles action.SEND which does some work and finishes.

```
<activity
        android:name=".StandaloneActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

It has transparent theme:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

StandaloneActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    handleIntentExtras(intent)
}

override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    handleIntentExtras(intent)
}
private fun handleIntentExtras(intent: Intent) {
// do some work and set extras to intent
//Calling setResult() as I start this activity from another activity with startActivityForResult() for another usecase.
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
    finish()
}
```

**Expected is, whenever a user shares something with my app from another app, user should not leave current app but StandaloneActivity should be able to do work and finish. StandaloneActivity (my app) should not remain in recents.**

The weird this is above setup works as expected in Java version of app but with Kotlin (migrating from Java to Kotlin) **StandaloneActivity (my app) is visible in recents and on opening it, it is processing the previous intent and getting finished. StandaloneActivity remains in the recents.**

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to recreate the same setup with a simple demo app and after playing around with diffrent launch modes and flags I got the solution.
I have to exclude this activity from the recents, so I added following to the StandaloneActivity in the manifest along with existing setup-

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```